# Is it better to loop in SQL or PHP here

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
SELECT voucherID FROM vouchers WHERE **lots of conditions**
```

Lets say I'm getting two voucherIDs 5 and 6.

Now for each of those voucherIDs I do an `INSERT` statement in which the `voucherID` appears in a condition.

Abstract pseudo code for the insert of the first of the two voucherID (=5):

```
INSERT INTO usevoucher(userID, voucherID)
   SELECT userID FROM users WHERE *lots of conditions including voucherID = 5* ,
   5 AS voucherID
   FROM ...
```

(Note that I'm using the `voucherID` as a constant)

Now I would repeat the above `INSERT` statement with the next `voucherID` 6

As far as I can see there's no solution for doing all this in one statement.

Is it better to save the results of the first `SELECT` (5 and 6) into an Array in PHP and then loop through the array doing the inserts

**or**
is it better to loop directly in MySQL (using While, Repeat or For Loop)?
(for best performance and code style)

**Edit:**

Example:

```
SELECT voucherID FROM vouchers WHERE active = 1
```

Result:

```
VoucherID
5
6
```

Those are the vouchers relevant for my insert.
Now all users who don't have the voucher yet in ownsvoucher are supposed to get the voucher.

```
ownsvoucher
UserID    VoucherID    
44        5
50        6
60        NULL
70        NULL
```

User 50, 60 and 70 don't have voucherID 5, so I need to insert

```
50       5
60       5
70       5
```

User 44, 60 and 70 don't have voucherID 6, so I need to insert

```
44      6
60      6
70      6
```

Comment: Do you really need a loop? A basic INSERT with SELECT is the ideal solution here.

Comment: Have you tried a CASE statement in that SELECT to populate the voucherID ?

Comment: If the conditions may vary and more logic is needed, it could be better to do it in PHP as you could write tests for it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a simple [`INSERT INTO ... SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html) in this case:

```
INSERT INTO usevoucher (userID, voucherID)
    SELECT userID, voucherID 
    FROM users 
    WHERE (<your-conditions>) AND voucherID IN (5, 6, 7, 8, ...)
```

Solution based on your edit:

```
INSERT INTO ownsvoucher (userID, voucherID)
  SELECT users.userID, vouchers.voucherID 
  FROM (users, vouchers) 
    LEFT JOIN ownsvoucher ov ON ov.userID = users.userID AND ov.voucherID = vouchers.voucherID 
  WHERE vouchers.active = 1 AND ov.voucherID IS NULL
```

In case you want to filter for specific `voucherID` you can add `AND vouchers.voucherID IN (5, 6)`.

> [**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=516dafc22ba8ee2831f76f714b6d2b98)

Comment: I don't think this wouldn't work since the numbers (5,6,7,8) need to correspond to the specific voucherID given in `(<your-conditions>)`.  The condition varies

Comment: @RolfWolf Show your full query, some example data and the expected result. In case you only provide the list of `voucherID` from PHP it should be possible. The full query would be very helpful.

Comment: I updated my question and added an example that hopefully makes it more clear.

Comment: should also work: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=89d8d8a5d529064e696bde6b7bc41591 (only added 80 to users table).